# Determine if list of bulk URLs are dead, live, or parked

Tags: html

There's a list of 100s of URLs that need to be checked to determined if the sites are live (someone has put their own content, even if just a landing), unreachable, or parked.

Unreachable is self explanatory, but distinguishing between actual user content and a parked domain is trickier. What I mean to say is someone who's hosting a domain through GoDaddy and uses their default landing page versus a hosted site with unique content as a landing page.

Using http codes (2xx,3xx,4xx,etc) isn't reliable. Does anyone know of a solution? It doesn't need to be 100% accurate in all instances, just accurate when it says it's accurate in order to minimise manual checking.

The best solution I can come up with is seeing who the site is registered with and comparing the code against other sites also registered there where matches >.9 or something to that effect. This is clunky.

Are there any ready-made solutions for this problem? If not, is there a more efficient methodology?

Comment: you can use any server side language and also if possible use any hosting sites itself to find if a URL is available or not.. You can program to hit this site and check for URL availability... Since these sites provide valid messages something like "Not available" … "Available" … "Bidding in process" etc etc.. With these messages may be you can judge the result..

Comment: Parse the content of each page and look for certain keywords?